# Looking for some numerical examples of the Decomposition Group and the Inertia Group

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-number-theory

Where can I find some worked out examples of the decomposition group and inertia group ?

Comment: Another question from you seems to be related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2003841

Comment: See chapter 4 of D. Marcus' book, in particular on p. 103.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2142683